# Rails 4: Delayed job keep cache for email "from" header value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, delayed-job, mailing

I am developing a mailing web application in Ruby on Rails and I am in front of an issue with delayed_job gem:

In the settings of my application, I give the ability for the customer to update the email address from where mailing are sent. But I discovered there was something like a cache from delayed_job which doesn’t use the update email address for the « from » header.

When I use the delayed_job task by Capistrano manually it works so I tried to add a callback after_update in my model to handle the restart of delayed_job but without any success.

Capistrano command:

```
cap <my_env> delayed_job:restart # this works but it’s a manual command so useless in my case
```

What I tried is to dynamically restart delayed_job from the model:

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :restart_delayed_job

  def restart_delayed_job
    if email_changed?
      system "RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env} do bundle exec bin/delayed_job -n 1 restart"
    end
  end
end
```

My Mailing class:

```
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: Setting.first.email # After updating the email value in setting, it still the old one used.
  # more code skipped
end
```

Does anyone knows how can I restart delayed_job from Rails ?
Is there a way to do it exclusively in Ruby without writing shell script ?
In order to help me to understand better, is there several instance of delayed_job (one by website in the server) or one for all website ?

Thanks for your help !

**My project**:
  - Rails 4.2.5
  - Ruby 2.2.2
  - ActiveAdmin 1.0.0 pre2
  - Delayed job 4.1.1
  - Capistrano 3.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to move the `from` header into the `mail` function.
The reason is the default from is set only once when the application start and cannot be changed this way.

```
mail(from: email, subject: subject, ...) do
  # skipped code
end
```

Here is the answer who helped me to understand that: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/882